# facebook batch request for multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-batch-request, multiple-users

I have a user database from facebook. I want to get their data (interests and friends birthdays) using batch request. Now I can make 1 batch request for 1 user. But considering the no. of users in my app is huge definately it will reach a limit.

I want to know if there is any way to get multiple users data in a batch request

I tried the following but it didn't work

"access_token": "USER_A_ACCESS_TOKEN",
batch=[ 
   {"method": "GET", "access_token": "USER_A_ACCESS_TOKEN", "relative_url": "me/friends"},
   {"method": "GET", "access_token": "USER_B_ACCESS_TOKEN", "relative_url": "me/friends"} 
      ]

For userB access token also i get results for user A access token

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation on the batch requests page

```
The Batch API is flexible and allows individual requests to specify their own
access tokens as a query string or form post parameter. In that case the top
level access token is considered a fallback token and is used if an individual
request has not explicitly specified an access token.
```

Rewriting your original attempt should be like this

curl -F "access_token=USER_A_ACCESS_TOKEN" -F 'batch=[{"method": "GET", "relative_url": "me/friends?access_token=USER_A_ACCESS_TOKEN"}, {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "me/friends?access_token=USER_B_ACCESS_TOKEN"}]'

The original USER_A_ACCESS_TOKEN will be used as a fallback if there is an error with any of the other access_tokens

Comment: Note that Facebook's docs claim that you can also include the access_token in the "json" portion (e.g. within each logical request within the `batch` JSON).  Unfortunately, there appears to be a long-lived bug in the Graph API that prevents this from working.  (http://stackoverflow.com/q/10396911/114558)  So, the approach shown here, in which the `access_token` is appended to the URL, seems to be the only working configuration.