# Facebook Graph Batch, only takes top-level access_token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm using the Facebook Graph Batch API to send one message / different messages to registered people's FB walls.
I'm defining an access_token for each user, and the obliged top-level access_token (used as fallback, according to the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)). For the latter I just use an access_token from the users listed in the batch.

The thing is that the only user recieving the message, is the one who's access_token I used as the top-level/fallback access_token.
The other users get the "(#210) User not visible" error message.
I'm using 3 test users setup at my app-roles.

Any idea what goes wrong here?

Here's my code (python) for generating one message to all registrants:

```
    for soc_reg in self.registrants:
        batch_item = {
            "method" : "POST",
            "relative_url" : FACEBOOK_URL_FEED % (soc_reg['uid']),
            "body" : Helper.toURL(publishParams),
            "access_token" : soc_reg['access_token'],
        }
        batch.append(batch_item)
    params = {
        "access_token" : self.registrants[0]['access_token'], # used as fallback
        "batch" : Helper.toJSON(batch),
    }
```

results in following value for "params":

```
{"access_token": "XYZ", "batch": "[{\"body\": \"caption=&message=is+not+a+test.%0D%0AWe%27re+just+rappin%27+to+the+beat%21&place=146270405429726&link=&description=\", \"access_token\": \"XYZ\", \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"/100003720771245/feed\"}, {\"body\": \"caption=&message=is+not+a+test.%0D%0AWe%27re+just+rappin%27+to+the+beat%21&place=146270405429726&link=&description=\", \"access_token\": \"ZYX\", \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"/100003671211957/feed\"}, {\"body\": \"caption=&message=is+not+a+test.%0D%0AWe%27re+just+rappin%27+to+the+beat%21&place=146270405429726&link=&description=\", \"access_token\": \"YZX\", \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"/100003683601909/feed\"}]"}
```

So the only user recieving the message is the one defined here: "access_token" : self.registrants[0]['access_token']
When I adjust the index, I can determine the one recieving the message ;)

Comment: Can you please file a bug in the Facebook [Platform Bug Tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)? This sounds like it may be erroneous behaviour.

Comment: I'd like to, but how can I submit a bug? Can't see any create-button or what so ever. Do I need to be a special-type-of-developer to be allowed to do that?

Comment: Sorry for being so blind!: Bottom of search hinting-list...

Comment: Reported this at Facebook Platform Bug Tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/297052017044229

Comment: Seems like it's rather quiet around this possible bug..
Anybody else experienced sort of the same problem I had regarding this Facebook Graph Batch API?

Answer (score 1):

OK, seems like the documentation and the API itself are not corresponding:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/212455918831996

Documentation says:
relative_url => 'alias', 'body' => '{"access_token" => "..."}'

But only this ways seems to work:
'relative_url' => 'alias?access_token=...'

FB seemed to have confirmed the bug and put it on the 'wishlist', so far the latter is the way to go, works for me at least :)

Comment: Verified that this is still the case, even several years later... :/